# Lightning new URL format navigate to visualforce

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, url

In current code we use something like:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/apex/TestVisualforcePage"
```

Anyone knows how we can convert this so it works with the new lightning URL format?

I tried for example  `"/lightning/alohaRedirect/apex/TestVisualforcePage"` or `"/lightning/apex/TestVisualforcePage"` but it does not work.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax `/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/apex/TestVisualforcePage` is not dead yet and will continue to work. As stated here it's not recommended if there is an alternative, but sometimes there is still no alternative.

In one scenario on a current project, we have a CTI adapter that opens a screen pop in a new window, and we want the new window to pop open to a particular Visualforce page with the Lightning one.app wrapper around it, and pass parameters to the VF page. The CTI adapter does not have access to `sforce.one` or any Lightning events. In this situation we decided to use the `alohaRedirect` syntax because we simply could not find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using `<apex:outputLink value="/lightning/n/yourVFPageName"/>` and i have used like this and it works for me.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this in my org with the new URL format enabled.

Comment: I think what you're describing might only work if it's already a Tab.

Comment: Yes i had a Visualforce tab earlier, but after removing the tab, i was able to access the page using `<apex:outputLink value="/apex/yourVFPageName"/>`.

Comment: Yes if you're navigating from within a Visualforce context already you can access it that way. However if you visit that URL directly it will load without the one.app wrapper.